# What happens when the information of the graduate application and the recommender does not match?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I have applied for Ph.D. positions in US universities (still applying) and I asked one of my collaborators to write a recommendation letter for me. She has my CV. Today she sent me a copy to check if everything's alright (though it was submitted in some universities already). I checked there is a mistake. I mean I have graduated in Chemical biology but she wrote Chemistry.

In this case, what should I do? I mean I can ask her to correct it. But what about the LORs that already has been sent? Will it have a very negative impact on my application?

Comment: What did you say what you have studied in your CV? What course did she teach you?

Comment: She's a collaborator on one of my research projects.

Comment: What was the research project about? Chemical biology? Chemistry?

Comment: I mean I graduated in Chemical biology. But she wrote - 'I know he studied Chemistry..'